# GETH - BAD BLOCK : Error: invalid merkle root - Transactions and block stuck in pendings

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, synchronization, pending-transactions

I'm having problems with geth when I try to send transactions on my private blockchain being developed using Geth.

Practically a block is blocked in pending with around twenty transactions inside it and I am neither able to perform a dump of this block nor am I able to unblock the transactions. I've tried everything, caching, transaction resend, syncronization, but nothing works:

Below is the full error message:

```
########## BAD BLOCK #########

Block: 28 (0xf21aeec5ec4982f0693f61048813f0829ead7eada38f61278a213a3fb18b4176)

Error: invalid merkle root (remote: c483e99bb2c3f0c881099ff0a1c985bf7b9826f8c5562656aa04a380549e0a6e local: 9ce45c7ab39ce7d9b58ff2bb71449652853ed6f192c2e59eb8f4df3e8f700a96) dberr: %!w(<nil>)

Platform: geth (devel) go1.20.3 amd64 linux

VCS: e501b3b0-

Chain config: &params.ChainConfig{ChainID:10001, HomesteadBlock:0, DAOForkBlock:<nil>, DAOForkSupport:false, EIP150Block:0, EIP155Block:0, EIP158Block:0, ByzantiumBlock:0, ConstantinopleBlock:0, PetersburgBlock:0, IstanbulBlock:0, MuirGlacierBlock:<nil>, BerlinBlock:0, LondonBlock:<nil>, ArrowGlacierBlock:<nil>, GrayGlacierBlock:<nil>, MergeNetsplitBlock:<nil>, ShanghaiTime:(*uint64)(nil), CancunTime:(*uint64)(nil), PragueTime:(*uint64)(nil), TerminalTotalDifficulty:<nil>, TerminalTotalDifficultyPassed:false, Ethash:(*params.EthashConfig)(nil), Clique:(*params.CliqueConfig)(0xc0004f2d00)}

Receipts:

  0: cumulative: 260452 gas: 260452 contract: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 status: 1 tx: 0x83692ef807db25d0ae74bd32422334fa08233116232b3f2660462d32e190a325 logs: [] bloom: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 state:

##############################
```

Can anyone provide me support on this issue?

Comment: Did you modify geth source code? How many nodes there's on the network? Are all the nodes using the same source? From the source it seems there's a mismatch between the remote and local clients. Was there a fork in the network?

Comment: Hi, no, i haven't modify source code. There are 2 node on a machine and 1 node in another machine. 

The machines are a linux system with 4 GB RAM so i don't think is a problem related to this.

No, there wasn't a fork

Comment: I also posted on geth issue, you can see here other details: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/28154